# Gridview onrowupdating do not pick up new values

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The gridview's code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="uxItemsGV" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" 
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="20" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowEditing="uxItemsGV_RowEditing"
                onpageindexchanging="uxItemsGV_PageIndexChanging" 
                onpageindexchanged="uxItemsGV_PageIndexChanged" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
                onrowupdated="uxItemsGV_RowUpdated" onrowupdating="uxItemsGV_RowUpdating" 
                onrowcancelingedit="uxItemsGV_RowCancelingEdit">
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Item ID" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Title" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityOnHand" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Totalsold" HeaderText="Total Sold" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RetailPrice" HeaderText="SR Price" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Dateofadd" HeaderText="Added Date" ReadOnly="true" />
                </Columns>
                <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" FirstPageText="First" 
                    LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="&gt;&gt;" 
                    PreviousPageText="&lt;&lt;" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

The code behind:

```
protected void uxItemsGV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = uxItemsGV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        try
        {
            BVController.Updateitem(int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text), Session["CategoryID"].ToString(), ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text.Trim(),
                int.Parse(((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text.Trim()), decimal.Parse(((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text.Trim()),
                int.Parse(((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.Trim()));
            uxUserMessage.Text = "Item " + row.Cells[1].Text + " has been updated.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            uxUserMessage.Text = "The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            MsgBlock.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

When I clicked update link the code said the update done, but no change has been made. I set breakpoint and found the code just pass old values to commit the update. No any new value be picked up. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have any edit controls in the grid, and I don't see any place to change the information.

Comment: I have added "AutoGenerateEditButton="True"" in the gridview tag. It automatic add a Edit column in the gridview.

Comment: Just because an edit button is shown doesn't mean that the fields are editable. Do you see editable fields when you click the edit button?

Comment: I used Google chrome to inspect the onrow textbox elements and saw their value was still the old one. While the textboxes shown new inputs on me.

Comment: @James Yes, when I click edit button, there is update and cancel button and the columns in the row changed to editable textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the edit templates, like such:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval(<Column Name>)%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval(<Column Name>)%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                                
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After you've done this, you need to change you OnRowUpdating event to pull the values from the templated edit controls.

Comment: I have tried this way and changed the boundfield to templatefield, used TextBox nt = (TextBox)(row.FindControl("newTitle"));. But the "newTitle" still pass the old value.

Comment: Please see the other answer I posted a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the DataField (column name) To access the new values, like in the following example:

```
int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewValues["CategoryID"]);
string firstName = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["FirstName"]);
```

Comment: Any example code for e.NewValues? Given EditItemTemplate textbox id="newTitle". Thanks.

Comment: There is an error message for the code: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'."

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast anything as type TextBox. The NewValues collection should contain all of your updated values. Am I missing something??

Comment: The code I typed is : "string ntt = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["itemName"]);", and got the above error message. The value of ntt is actually null.

Comment: protected void uxItemsGV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {string ntt = Convert.ToString(e.NewValues["ItemName"]); uxUserMessage.Text = "New title: " + ntt;}

Comment: I think you need to look at your markup. I don't think this code that's causing the problem. There is a type conflict somewhere, and it probably has something to do with the uxUserMessage control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was caused by this.BindGrid() being called incorrectly in Page_Load

Comment: you might want to example on the answer by adding a code example